# NodeJS - Can't determine/validate incoming form-data as all of it is considered as string

Tags: json, node.js, string, form-data, body-parser

Recently I've been trying to validate a "form-data" request using coming from Postman.
I noticed that every time I am trying to validate/filter the incoming variables, they are all strings, even if those strings values can be converted to a Number/Boolean, etc - As I want to validate what theyr'e "true" Type is.
While Trying to find a solution, I have tried to use "typeof", and the following dependencies: "[validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)", "[express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator)".
I must mention body-parser is in place:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

They are all being "fooled" and consider the variables as strings.
What I assume happens, is because of the way body-parser is implemented, they are all being parsed as JSON, which results them being strings.
Assuming this, I have tried to use `JSON.parse` which worked great (when trying it on a number for example), but crashed when using it on strings:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token D in JSON at position 0
```

"D" is the start of the string ("Doe"), it crashed after trying to parse the first letter.

The thing is, I do want to parse the incoming request as JSON, but I do want to filter, numbers being send as first name, for example.

The best way to achieve that / filter incoming form-data?
Thank you.

Edit:
Added a picture describing the request, no additional headers besides the ones shown.
[image]

Comment: Can you share some screenshots or codes? @StackMaster

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot you posted, you are not posting JSON to the server. This explains the syntax error when parsing JSON.

What you are parsing is form data which has a different format from JSON. Form data looks something like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="boundary" 

--boundary 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName" 

John 
--boundary 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastName"

Doe
--boundary 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="street"

Example Address

.... etc
```

Obviously the above looks nothing like JSON.

To send JSON you must select the "raw" format then paste in your own manually constructed JSON data.

Comment: Hi Slebetman,
You are right, but I do not want to post JSON. I want to validate the incoming form-data, using the current request type.
I am trying to do so, but currently can't determine the variable's type correctly, for example:
Let's say I am receiving "123456" value for the zip code field inside the request, what's the best way to validate that it is really a number?
Thank you.

Comment: All incoming data are strings. Thus the usual way to validate it-looks-like-a-number is using regular expressions. Then once you've validated what the data should look like you can convert it to a number using Number or parseInt. But be warned, zip codes are not numbers, they are strings. You will have countries (like the UK) where the zip code look something like 237WC3